# DAX 'AND' Operator error in power bi measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple DAX formula that i want to use to distinct count the number of customers who have met a certain criteria. I have a table that defines these criteria i.e Tiers I am doing this on power bi and this is the measure that i am using;

```
MTierB = 
var y = SUM('Brand Tiers'[TierB]),
var x = SUM('Brand Tiers'[TierA])                                                                           
return CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Sales By Customers'[CUSTOMER_StoreCode]), 

KEEPFILTERS(FILTER('Sales By Customers', 'Sales By Customers'[Total Sales in 

MSU] >= y AND <=x )))
```

I am getting a syntax error. The AND operator is underlined in red and i dont understand why? Please help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DAX, `AND` is a function where `AND(a,b)` means "a and b". ([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634379.aspx))

You can use `&&` as a logical conjunction instead though. That is, `AND(a,b) == a && b`

In your case, you need the `FILTER` part of your measure to look like this

```
FILTER('Sales By Customers',
       'Sales By Customers'[Total Sales in MSU] >= y &&
       'Sales By Customers'[Total Sales in MSU] <= x)
```

or like this

```
FILTER('Sales By Customers',
       AND('Sales By Customers'[Total Sales in MSU] >= y,
           'Sales By Customers'[Total Sales in MSU] <= x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Kevin,

Also, no commas between the variable statements.

```html
MTierB =
VAR y =    SUM ( 'Brand Tiers'[TierB] ) // no comma
VAR x =    SUM ( 'Brand Tiers'[TierA] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Sales By Customers'[CUSTOMER_StoreCode] ),
        KEEPFILTERS (
            FILTER (
                'Sales By Customers',
                'Sales By Customers'[Total Sales in MSU] >= y
                    && 'Sales By Customers'[Total Sales in MSU] <= x
            )
        )
    )
```